# Magento: 50 addresses for a customer hangs the browser

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I am having a strange situation with magento, when I am trying to add about 60 addresses for one customer, then till 50 it works fine but after that when I try to add more addresses and click Save button Firefox gives `Script Busy warning` and asks to stop or debug the script. When I stop script or debug it, and then re-try to save it saves OK.

I have not made any changes in magento core, it is by default latest install and it gives such error.

What could be the issue and how I can fix this?

Comment: Probably not it as it would appear to be a general php/db but there is a maximum number of allowed shipping addresses set in System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Settings.  Worth a look perhaps?

Comment: Hi @JonHolland I have checked those settings but those are for shipping address at the time of checkout, but in my case I am not able to add more than 50 address from admin panel for single customer. If I add more than 50 address for one customer and try to save that customer in admin panel, it hangs and doesn't save.

Comment: Yer, I didn't really expect that to be the issue, but 50 seems too much of a nice round number to be a coincidence.

Comment: @JonHolland Could you please suggest something, what should I do to resolve this? Can't say no to customer for adding 50 address, without any proof or reason. Magento have no such limitations mentioned anywhere. I have tested the same thing in fresh magento install and that is also hangs after 50 address for one customer in admin panel :(